# Using jQuery Cookie to save referer URL and display a certain phone number

Tags: jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

So I'm trying to get and store a referrer URL using jquery cookie. What I would like to happen is if someone comes in from Google or Facebook or any other site (other than direct) then they would get a specific phone number (888-888-888). If someone types in the site directly then the referrer URL will not set or be seen as direct and display a different phone number (123-456-7890). Below is the code I'm using but it does not seem to work:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if (!jQuery.cookie("urlCookie")) {
        var url = document.referrer;
        var match = url.indexOf("acmeco.com");
        if (match != -1) {
            jQuery.cookie("urlCookie", url);
            jQuery("#phone-anchor").text('888-888-8888');
        }
    } else {
        jQuery("#phone-anchor").text('123-456-7890');
    }
});
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to deal with cookies first and then check it and change a phone number:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    if (!jQuery.cookie("urlCookie")) {
        jQuery.cookie("urlCookie", document.referrer);
    }

    var url = jQuery.cookie("urlCookie");
    var match = url.indexOf("acmeco.com");

    if (match != -1) {
        jQuery("#phone-anchor").text('888-888-8888');
    } else {
        jQuery("#phone-anchor").text('123-456-7890');
    }
});
```